# Apache service in XAMPP does not start

Tags: xampp

The following error is generating and it has wasted my whole day for solution. Please help with concrete solution if somebody has solution. Here is the screen shot.
[image] 
The error message is showing like the procedure entry point ucerbase.terminate could not be located in the dynamic link library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll

Answer (score 0):

Try to install this Windows update: https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows